# Separate first name and last name on filename

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with with user names as file name. The problem is that some of them are properly formatted and others are not. 
example

```
Good = Jane Doe.bmp
Bad = JaneDoe.bmp
```

What I was thinking is first to find if the name has any space in it. If not then find the first instance of the upper case and add an space.

Any ideas what will the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What about `FredMcBride`? `DJJazzyJeff`?

Comment: Yes there are also Jon D Dean but the bulk of it is simple FirstLast. The others could be updated by hand. Thanks

Comment: Now this is just a general rule I follow and is in no way standard practice or system breaking. I tend not to add spaces in my file names. I'll typically use camel humping or Hungarian notation in my file naming conventions as much as in my coding. Main reason I do this is that my system tends to replace spaces with % when traversing the directories through dos commands.

Comment: Thats correct. The only reason for this is that I built an app that has the names from a system that uses the user name and I'm trying to get their picture from existing photos that someone else has taken in the past. The other way to have match up is to make the photos and the username string to have not spaces. So removing spaces from file names will also work. Thank you for bringing this good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
  $outfile = $_ -creplace '(\p{Ll})(\p{Lu})', '$1 $2'
   Move-Item $_ $outfile
}
```

Comment: To handle zero or more spaces, shouldn't the regex be `-creplace '(\p{Ll})(\s*)(\p{Lu})', '$1 $3'`

Comment: @KeithHill perhaps you can add your own answer